How to add context to Vercel AI SDK's useChat without exposing it to the user
At the beginning of the chat, I want to give a large text that will give the context to the ChatGPT session on what he needs to know to efficiently answer the user's prompts.
I tried using append() to add some context, but it shows the message to the user with the large context text which I don't want. I tried to add context to the data or body, but I don't seem to understand, and Vercel AI SDK documentation sucks in this regard.
Has anyone faced this issue? How can I resolve it?
This is what I tried:
 appendMessage({
  id: "1",
  role: "data",
  content: problemData.startingCode,
});

const newChatRequestOptions: ChatRequestOptions = {
  options: {
    body: {
      context: problemData.startingCode,
    },
  },
  data: {
    context: problemData.startingCode,
  },
};
handleSubmit(e, newChatRequestOptions);

However Chat still does not get that info from the body or from the data.

"With streamText, you can set a system prompt separate from the messages."
Here's the answer: https://github.com/vercel/ai/discussions/1869

The append function now includes a data attribute:
I would send it like this:
append({
  role: "user",
  content: `content`,
  data: "server context",
});

Inside route.ts (API/chat), you can retrieve the last message in your messages array, which will contain the data attribute. You can then use streamText and include .data as part of the system prompt or your messages.
const userMessage = messages[messages.length - 1]; Then just check for userMessage.data
